# I am trying to run Kafka Consumer and Producer In Spring Boot Eclipse. But getting time out error

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Does anyone have Kafka Producer Consumer Spring Boot Example. I am trying two or three sample code but getting error.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: And the actual code as well.

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/garg-geek/kafka/tree/master/kakfa-producer-consumer-example @DinaBogdan

Comment: I don't have enought time to watch on the entire project. Post the stacktrace here, please

Comment: Please add the code and stacktrace to give fair idea of what you are trying.